# Pause an animation. In addition, get its position

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a rectangle where i am using a story board to rotate it up like a needle in a car gauge( mph). What i want to do is be able to pause it. In addition i would also like to get its location when i want to.  Like get its current value as its rotating up to the end position that i specified. Can this be done?

What i want to do is use that to calculate the tachometer and move the tachometer needle according to the mph story board.

```
 DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
        da.From = 0 * 6;
        da.To = 60;
        da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
        rt.CenterX = 35;
        rt.CenterY = 0;
        rec3.RenderTransform = rt;
        rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);




        DoubleAnimation tack = new DoubleAnimation();
        tack.From = 0 * 6;
        tack.To = 30;
        tack.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        RotateTransform tackneedle = new RotateTransform();
        tackneedle.CenterX = 30;
        tackneedle.CenterY = 0;
        rec4.RenderTransform = tackneedle;
        tackneedle.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, tack);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your animations to a Storyboard which will allow you to pause and resume the animation. You should also be able to access the rotate transforms and get the value of their centers.

Answer (score 0):

A different way might be more appropriate:

Make a class that calculates/generates the value.

Bind the needle to the value (use a value converter to get from amount to angle if needed)

that way you can control the value more easily and you can always stop the animation by pausing the generation of the value.

You have to think about what you need: do you need to know the value of the animation or should the needle follow/display the value?